# Replace without finding next match

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace

Is there a way to only replace the current match in the current editor/file, without going to the next match in `Visual Studio Code`?

The replace button has the functionality of *replace, find next match and scroll to the position of the next match*.

With complex RegEx replacements I sometimes want to see the result of the replacement before going to the next.

Comment: you can add a feature request in the VSC repo

Comment: @rioV8 I tried for other features, but you need 20 people to like it on GitHub within a month or it will be autoclosed by a bot. I do not see a chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you want is to disable the setting:

`Editor > Find: Cursor Move On Type`

Not an obvious setting but it works to only replace the current match and not move to the next.

Comment: Perfect, because it uses the jump to next match when pressing replace again. The description for that setting is very confusing though: `controls whether the cursor should jump to matches while typing`. I am not typing, when I click on the replace button.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to replace all occurrences without having to go one by one you can achieve this by using the left side menu.

1.Search for the occurrence you would like to replace

2.Toggle the arrow next to it [image]

3.Write the replacement string

4.Click on save all next to it.

5.You'll be asked if to do replace all for all the occurrences in the whole project. click yes and there you have it.

Comment: No I meant replacing only the current matched occurrence.